# mod_rewrite Configuration for No Extensions and PHP Handling

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I am trying to drop extensions and enable access such that requests for "/", "/index", and "/index.ext" all return the same resource.

At the same time, I want every such resource to go through a PHP script that includes a header, footer, and does other processing before sending it back to the client as the resource they requested.

How do I do this using only .htaccess? Even with MultiViews off, I've hit a brick wall where every attempt results in an infinite rewrite loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on

# Route all requests on non-existent directories and files to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [L,QSA]
```

You might also check out [AskApache's excellent HowTo's](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-tips-and-tricks.html) for more mod_rewrite recipes.

Answer (score 1):

Exclude static files (.js, .css etc):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ /index.php
```

Exclude the same static files but allow real files and directories:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ /index.php
```

As recommended by the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Configuring+Your+URL+Rewriter).

Comment: +1 `!\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$` - Good call, makes sense to skip PHP if the resource type isn't supported

Comment: The first one results in another infinite rewrite loop and produces a 500 error. The second one works but it doesn't allow me to do any processing outside of the requested file. Basically I need a way to pass the value of the page to the handler script so that it can be included between includes of the header and footer.